# multi-dimensional array in python using numpy.where

Tags: python

I am a beginner with python and am going through a tutorial but could not achieve the proper results.

I would like to know where I could have gone wrong!

```
binFreq = np.arange(N / 2 + 1) * float(fs) / N
squaredMX = np.square(mX)
lowBandIdx0 = np.where(binFreq > 0)[0][0]

lowBandIdx3000 = np.where(binFreq < 3000)[0][-1]

highBandIdx3000 = np.where(binFreq > 3000)[0][0]

highBandIdx10000 = np.where(binFreq < 10000)[0][-1]

lowBandSqMX = squaredMX[:,lowBandIdx0:lowBandIdx3000+1]
highBandSqMX = squaredMX[:,highBandIdx3000:highBandIdx10000+1]
engEnv = np.zeros((numFrames, 2))
engEnv[:, 0] = 10*np.log10(np.sum(lowBandSqMX, 1))
engEnv[:, 1] = 10*np.log10(np.sum(highBandSqMX, 1))
```

I would especially like to understand what these lines do:

```
lowBandIdx3000 = np.where(binFreq < 3000)[0][-1]
highBandIdx10000 = np.where(binFreq < 10000)[0][-1]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to show us what output you want, what you are getting, and any error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This gives an array of indexes where the condition, `binFreq < 10000` is True. I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but hopefully this helps! You can do a small test like this to show what I'm saying.'

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([4,2,3,1,5])
b = numpy.where(a<3)
print(b)#[1,3]
```